# Support for der file

Tags: opc-ua, der, milo

Does eclipse.milo opc-ua sdk provide .der file support, I see examples with pfx files but I am looking for .der file example. Please share required details

Comment: You'll need to provide a little more information about what you're trying to do. Milo can parse DER files into certificates but that may not be relevant.

Comment: I have opc-ua server which supports only der file so I am trying to create opc-ua java client to communicate with existing opc-ua server by establish communication using .der file